# Zephyr - Bluetooth - NRF52 DK - selection one channel of advertising

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

Is it possible in Zephyr to advertise and scan through Bluetooth only on single channel ( for example channel37)? I found some file III_chan with channel selection algorithms and I wonder: do i need to change this file somehow or theere is some simple way to do this?